# Filter a Dataframe Based Upon A List - However Contains

Tags: r

I want to use a list of text values to filter a dataframe HOWEVER I want the list value to be a contains.

I'd also like to be case insensitive.

Any help is appreciated.

Lou

Code:

```
a = c("Louis","Frank")
MyFilteredData <- MyData[MyData$Singer %in% a,]
```

Data Example:

```
Singer
"Frank Sinatra"
"Louis Armstrong"
"Bing Crosby"
```

The result of my filter would just be:

```
"Frank Sinatra"
"Louis Armstrong"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, we can use `grep` as the matches are partial

```
MyData[grep(paste0("\\b(", paste(a, collapse="|"), ")\\b"), 
          MyData$Singer),, drop = FALSE]
```

---

Or an option in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
MyData %>%
     filter(str_detect(Singer, str_c(a, collapse="|")))
```

Comment: Isn’t this a duplicate? And probably need to deal with the request for case insensitive.

Comment: @42-  If it is a duplicate, please tag it